# shared_from_this called from constructor

Tags: c++, boost

I have to register an object in a container upon its creation.
Without smart pointers I'd use something like this:

```
a_class::a_class()
{
    register_somewhere(this);
}
```

With smart pointers I should use `shared_from_this` but I can't use that in the constructor.

Is there a *clean* way to solve this problem? What would you do in a similar situation? 
I'm thinking about introducing an `init` method to call just after creation and put everything in a factory function like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<a_class> create_a()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<a_class> ptr(new a_class);
    ptr->init();
    return ptr;
}
```

Is it fine or there is a standard procedure to follow in such cases?

**EDIT:** Actually my case is more complex. I have 2 object which shall maintain pointers each other. So the truth is I'm not "registering" but creating another object (let's say `b_class`) which requires `this` as a parameter. `b_class` receives `this` as a weak pointer and stores it.

I'm adding this because since you are giving me design advices (which are very appreciated) at least you can know what I'm doing:

```
a_class::a_class()
{
    b = new b_class(this);
}
```

In my program `a_class` is an entity and `b_class` is one of the concrete classes representing the state (in the constructor it's just the starting state). `a_class` needs a pointer to the current state and `b_class` needs to manipulate the entity.

`a_class` is responsible for creating and destroying b_class instances and thus maintains a shared_ptr to them but `b_class` need to manipulate `a_class` and thus maintains a weak pointer. `a_class` instance "survives" `b_class` instances.

Do you suggest to avoid using smart pointers in this case?

Comment: I can't see enough of your code but the obvious question is why does `register_somewhere` need a smart pointer? It's usually cleaner if an object doesn't manage its own lifetime (which is what assuming or requiring that it's going to be held by a smart pointer is a thin end of the wedge to). Whatever is creating the object should decided on the allocation strategy, static, automatic, dynamic managed by smart pointer, etc. If you can separate registration and ownership then so much the better.

Comment: Simple Solution: sourceforge.net/projects/shared-from-this-ctor/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `a_class` is responsible for creating and destroying `b_class` instances

...

> `a_class` instance "survives" `b_class` instances.

Given these two facts, there should be no danger that a `b_class` instance can attempt to access an `a_class` instance after the `a_class` instance has been destroyed as the `a_class` instance is responsible for destroying the `b_class` instances.

`b_class` can just hold a pointer to it's associated `a_class` instance. A raw pointer doesn't express any ownership which is appropriate for this case.

In this example it doesn't matter how the `a_class` is created, dynamically, part of a aggregated object, etc.  Whatever creates `a_class` manages its lifetime just as `a_class` manages the lifetime of the `b_class` which it instantiates.

E.g.

```
class a_class;

class b_class
{
public:
    b_class( a_class* a_ ) : a( a_ ) {}
private:
    a_class* a;
};

class a_class
{
public:
    a_class() : b( new b_class(this) ) {}
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<b_class> b;
};
```

Note, in this toy example there is no need for a `shared_ptr`, an object member would work just as well (assuming that you don't copy your entity class).

```
class a_class
{
public:
    a_class() : b( this ) {}
private:
    b_class b;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely need a shared_ptr during construction, it's best to have an 'init' function. In fact, this is the only decent approach I can think of. You should probably have a special function that creates objects of this type, to ensure `init()` is called, if you choose this path.

However, depending on what you're registering for, it may be a better idea to give whatever object you're registering with a plain pointer to the object in the constructor, rather than a shared_ptr. Then in the destructor, you can just unregister the object from the manager.

Comment: If the manager is asynchronous unregistering does not guarantee that your callback won't be called a millisecond after your object is destroyed. A combination of shared and weak pointers can solve such a race.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html

```
struct a_class : enable_shared_from_this<a_class> {
    a_class() {
        shared_ptr<a_class> ptr(this);
        register_somewhere(ptr);
    }
};
```

**Update:** here is a complete working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

struct a_class;
boost::shared_ptr<a_class> pa;

void register_somewhere(boost::shared_ptr<a_class> p)
{
    pa = p;
};

struct a_class : boost::enable_shared_from_this<a_class> {
private:
    a_class() {
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        boost::shared_ptr<a_class> ptr(this);
        register_somewhere(ptr);
    }

public:
    ~a_class() {
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

    static boost::shared_ptr<a_class> create()
    {
        return (new a_class)->shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<a_class> p(a_class::create());
}
```

Note the factory function a_class::create(). Its job is to make sure that only one reference counter gets created. Because

```
boost::shared_ptr<a_class> p(new a_class);
```

Results in creation of two reference counters and double deletion of the object.

Comment: I don't think this example is working: you may end having 2 different counters for the same pointer...

Comment: the correct header to include is `<boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>` not `<boost/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>`

Comment: Not a fan of the global/static external `pa` helper field here, as it's not thread-safe, for example. It's not clear how to make this approach work without such a hack. I think an init method is cleaner/less error-prone.

Comment: @AlastairMaw AFAICT that is just a stub implementation of the - otherwise unrelated - `register_somewhere` function. This was a given in the OP.

Comment: This method works only if `register_somewhere()` is guaranteed to hold the shared reference long enough. If it releases the pointer before you get a chance to call `shared_from_this()` you end up with a destroyed object. This can happen if `register_somewhere()` is e.g. a fast running process that calls back and releases, or if its implementation was commented out for whatever reason.

Comment: This example is contrived. One might as well then register in create...

Answer (score 1):

There is **no need** for **`shared_ptr`** in your code (as you show it and explain it). A `shared_ptr` is *only* appropriate for shared ownership.

Your `b_class` doesn't own it's `a_class`, in fact is even outlived by it, so it should merely keep an *observing* pointer.

If `b_class` is polymorphic and the manipulations of `a_class` involve altering its `b_class` pointer, you should use a `unique_ptr<b_class>`:

```
class a_class;
class b_class
{
  friend class a_class;
  a_class* mya;
  b_class(a_class*p)
  : mya(p) {}
public:
  virtual~b_class() {}   // required for unique_ptr<b_class> to work
  virtual void fiddle(); // do something to mya
};

class a_class
{
  std::unique_ptr<b_class> myb;
public:
  a_class()
  : myb(new b_class(this)) {}
  template<typename B>
  void change_myb()
  {
    myb.reset(new B(this));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a helper class for that problem:

```
template <class Impl>
class ImmediatelySharedFromThis : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Impl> {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<void, std::function<void(void*)>> MallocGuard;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Impl> SharedPtr;

    // disallow `new MyClass(...)`
    static void *operator new(size_t) = delete;
    static void *operator new[](size_t) = delete;
    static void operator delete[](void*) = delete;
protected:
    typedef std::pair<MallocGuard&, SharedPtr&> SharingCookie;

    ImmediatelySharedFromThis(SharingCookie cookie) {
        MallocGuard &ptr = cookie.first;
        SharedPtr &shared = cookie.second;
        // This single line contains the actual logic:
        shared.reset(reinterpret_cast<Impl*>(ptr.release()));
    }
public:
    // Create new instance and return a shared pointer to it.
    template <class ...Args>
    static SharedPtr create(Args &&...args) {
        // Make sure that the memory is free'd if ImmediatelySharedFromThis
        // is not the first base class, and the initialization
        // of another base class throws an exception.
        MallocGuard ptr(aligned_alloc(alignof(Impl), sizeof(Impl)), free);
        if (!ptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("OOM");
        }

        SharedPtr result;
        ::new (ptr.get()) Impl(SharingCookie(ptr, result),
                               std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return result;
    }

    static void operator delete(void *ptr) {
        free(ptr);
    }
};

class MyClass : public ImmediatelySharedFromThis<MyClass> {
    friend class ImmediatelySharedFromThis<MyClass>;

    MyClass(SharingCookie cookie, int some, int arguments) :
        ImmediatelySharedFromThis(cookie)
        // You can pass shared_from_this() to other base classes
    {
        // and you can use shared_from_this() in here, too.
    }
public:
    ....
};

...

std::shared_ptr<MyClass> obj = MyClass::create(47, 11);
```

A bit ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I wrote my own drop-in replacement for `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `enable_shared_from_this`. You can check it out at [Sourceforge](http://shared-from-this-ctor.sourceforge.net/).

It allows call of `shared_from_this()` **in constructor and destructor without helper functions** without space overhead compared to the standard enable_shared_from_this.

**Note:** creating shared_ptr's in dtors is only allowed as long as they are created only temporarily. That is, they are being destroyed before the dtor returns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
class MyClass: enable_shared_from_this<MyClass>
{
    public:
        //If you use this, you will die.
        MyClass(bool areYouBeingAnIdiot = true)
        {
            if (areYouBeingAnIdiot)
            {
                throw exception("Don't call this constructor! Use the Create function!");
            }

            //Can't/Don't use this or shared_from_this() here.
        }

        static shared_ptr<MyClass> Create()
        {
            shared_ptr<MyClass> myClass = make_shared<MyClass>(false);

            //Use myClass or myClass.get() here, now that it is created.

            return myClass;
        }
}

//Somewhere.
shared_ptr<MyClass> myClass = MyClass::Create();
```

(The constructor has to be public to be callable from a static member function, even an internal one...)