# Two step constructions for enable_shared_from_this object that needs to pass std::shared_ptr<self> to children created in constructor

Tags: c++11, design-patterns, smart-pointers

I know that additional initialization methods are *evil*, as they leave a very nasty option for having object half-constructed and as result all methods needs to check for this. But what about this situation?

```
class config;
class cfg_item final
{
    private:
        friend class config;
        cfg_item(std::weak_ptr<config> owner) : owner(owner) { }
        std::weak_ptr<config> owner;
}
class config final : private std::enable_shared_from_this<config>
{
    public:
        config()
        {
             items.emplace(std::make_shared<cfg_item>(weak_from_this())); // Will crash!
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cfg_item>> items;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<config> cfg = std::make_shared<config>();
}
```

*I KNOW WHY IT CRASHES*. The `std::shared_ptr` in the main is not yet initialized with shared pointer to config instance, so constructor does not know how to make `weak_from_this` and just raises `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception because there are no valid `std::shared_ptr` pointing to `this` at constructor's call time.

The question is: how can I avoided the whole thing? I believe the only way I see would be to add separate initialization method, which is *evil* as I've already mentioned...

As note about real code: the constructors loads `cfg_item` from external source. It is assumed that all `cfg_item`s are available for the entire lifetime of `config`. The weak pointers back to `config` are mandatory, as `cfg_item` must push all changes done to it back to `config` to save to external source

Comment: You can just embed a non-owning reference of `config` (like `config&` or  `std::reference_wrapper<config>`) rather than `weak_ptr<config>` in the class `cfg_item`. It should be safe because logically `owner` will live no longer than the `config` object unless you do something really crazy.

Comment: @FrankHB This is actually very good idea I missed three years ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401032/shared-from-this-called-from-constructor), there are strong arguments why an external initialization function is necessary. However, you rightfully write

> I know that additional initialization methods are evil, as they leave a very nasty option for having object half-constructed and as result all methods needs to check for this.

it's possible to reduce this problem. Say you have a class `foo`, with the protocol that each time a `foo` object is constructed, `foo::init()` needs to be called. Obviously, this is a brittle class (client code will eventually omit calls to `init()`).

So, one way is to make the (non-copy / non-move) constructors of `foo` `private`, and create a variadic static factory method that creates objects, then calls `init()`:

```
#include <utility>

class foo { 
private:
    foo() {}
    foo(int) {}
    void init() {}

public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    static foo create(Args &&...args) {
        foo f{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
        f.init();
        return f;
    }
};
```

In the following code

```
    template<typename ...Args>
    static foo create(Args &&...args) {
        foo f{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
        f.init();
        return f;
    }
```

note that this single method can be used for all constructors, regardless of their signature. Furthermore, since it is `static`, it is external to the constructor, and doesn't have the problems in your question.

You can use it as follows:

```
int main() {
    auto f0 = foo::create();
    auto f1 = foo::create(2);
    // Next line doesn't compile if uncommented
    // foo f2; 
}
```

Note that it's impossible to create an object without this method, and the interface doesn't even contain `init`.

Comment: Your answer is nice, but I missed one important thing in description - `config` class is injected via boost dependency injector and I have no way of controlling `config` allocation. Specially, I cannot move it to factory method. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430580/151150 sounds like being on the right track, but my `cfg_item` might outlive `config`, so I cannot just use raw pointers :-(

Comment: @PiotrK That *does* make it more difficult, then. All the best.